# Logstash : Unable to parse the date

Tags: java, date, logstash

I am using logstash kafka plugin to read certain data, which has date and Time recorded separately.

For eg. Time 13:06:04 Date 06.02.2014

Using various answers I am using the following filter to build the custom timestamp in logstash

```
 filter {
  if [type] == "kafka"{
  mutate{
   add_field => {
     "tempfield" => "%{Date} %{Time}"
   }
  }
  date{
   match => ["tempfield","dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"]
   target => "@timestamp"
   remove_field => ["tempfield"]
  }
 }
}
```

When I run ELK stack, the timestamp variable is assigned current timestamp value. It does not get updated or changed based on the real/mutated value.

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community - for starters, describe *doesn't work*

Comment: Edited!! hope that makes more sense.

Comment: You could just keep the `@timestamp` field that is there by default. Wherever you read the data is where you should fetch the `tempfield`

Comment: The default timestamp takes the current system time, however, I need the timestamp to be changed based on the values in the data.